# Flutter Dialog without title

Tags: flutter

My code

```
return Dialog(
  insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
  elevation: 0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Select a service"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(MdiIcons.close),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)
        )]
      ),
      body: Text("This is just a test")
      )
  ));
```

How can I remove the unwanted title area at top?

[image: Dialog with extra title]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Scaffod widget inside the Dialog! You don't actually need that.
Make it simple with Columns and Rows like this:

```
return Dialog(
  insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
  elevation: 0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
    child: Container(
          child: Column(childre: [
              Row(children:[Text("Select a service"), IconButton(
            icon: Icon(MdiIcons.close),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)
        )],
      ), // use this row for top bar and your action button, and use space between and wrap this row with a container for colors and etc
          Container(child: Text("This is just a test")) // use this Container for rest
      ])  
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the AppBar and create a custom

```
return Dialog(
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Scaffold(
                body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("Select a service"),
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text("This is just a test"),
                )
              ],
            ))));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself after 5 days. Just add `primary: false` for both **Scaffold** and **AppBar** will do.

```
    child: Scaffold(
      primary: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        primary: false,
```